# Detect if input has text every keypress jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

For those who can't wait, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnsemblante/kkhb49kg/2/) :)

I am developing this kind of logic and I know I will be using jQuery for this but the problem is I don't know how to do such thing or to start it.

I want everytime I type something on the `input` or the `input` has text I want the `.search-dropdown` will be shown. Also even if I copy & paste something on the input the `.search-dropdown` will also be shown. How do I do it ? I don't really know how to do it in jQuery :( Forgive me for it I'm still a newbie in jQuery world.

For better example just like the search bar in facebook everytime I type the search results will be shown :). Thanks in advance for your time and your answers :) Have a good day Sir/Mam.

By is my CSS and HTML code:

CSS:

```
.search-here{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px 10px
}

.search-dropdown{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ececec;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: none;
}

.search-dropdown a{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="box-a4">
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-here">
        <div class="search-dropdown">
                <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</a>
                <a href="#">Dolorum a aperiam nemo ex fuga esse at expedita sed quo sequi voluptas labore.</a>
                <a href="#">Dolorum a aperiam nemo ex fuga esse at expedita sed quo sequi voluptas labore, nihil assumenda quidem dolore illo, consequuntur neque quasi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: indeed I can't waith for jsfiddle, but there is no js code...

Comment: Yes there is no js code for I don't know how to do it :) Forgive me for that. Thanks

Comment: Use a datalist on HTML5 compliant browser

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$('input').on('input',function(){
  $('.search-dropdown').toggle(this.value.length > 0);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mjw0bgg6/)**

Comment: the dropdown will be hidden every second character.

Comment: This works great but I want that the search results will be permanently be shown even if I type something on the input because as what I notice the search results will hide everytime I type :) Can you show to me how it will be done Sir ? :) Thanks. Anyway thank you for this

Comment: What about pasting some text? I would use `input` event

Comment: @A.Wolff: change event will handle that

Comment: @MilindAnantwar It would once input loses focus, not sure this is expected behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff: it works in chrome even if the focus remain and text is pasted

Comment: @MilindAnantwar It doesn't if you paste text using mouse. It works if using keyboard BUT because the keyup event is fired, not change. This would handle all cases: `$('input').on('input', handler);` but IE8 doesn't support it, if that matters

Comment: @A.Wolff: Thanks.. i am sure OP should not be bothered about IE8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyup and on functions. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kkhb49kg/5/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.search-here').keyup(function() {
        if($('.search-here').val() == ""){
          $('.search-dropdown').hide();
        } else {
          $('.search-dropdown').show();
        }
    });    

    $('.search-here').on('paste', function () {
        $('.search-dropdown').show();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This works but what if the input don't have text ? The search results don't hide :) But anyway thank you for your time sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".search-here").on("change",function(){
    //code to show auto-complete dropdown goes here
})
$(".search-here").on("keyup",function(){
    $(this).trigger("change");
})
```

The above code will allow you to do something anytime the text inside the textbox changes.

Comment: Explain wath you are doing with this code so that its clear to understand

Comment: `change` doesn't run on every keypress, it runs when they leave the input field.